# Maximum cut, what is and what isn't?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

Was wondering how is this a maximum cut?

For example, isn't there a cut of 6 as oppose to 5?

Comment: Perhaps a way to partition the nodes into two disjoint subsets so that the number of edges connecting nodes in one subset to the other is maximal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could only be possible to cut every edge if the graph is bipartite (the cut itself would give the vertex bipartition).  The given example is not a bipartite graph (e.g. it contains a $K_3$).